# "ghosts" slashes, adding item to a json file? what do I do?

Tags: php, json, redactor

This is my original json file

**data.json** (before)

```
[
{ "thumb": "../userfiles/img/min/m_1.jpg", "image": "../userfiles/img/1.jpg", "title": "Image 1", "folder": "Folder 1" },
{ "thumb": "../userfiles/img/min/m_2.jpg", "image": "../userfiles/img/2.jpg", "title": "Image 2", "folder": "Folder 1" },
{ "thumb": "../userfiles/img/min/m_3.jpg", "image": "../userfiles/img/3.jpg", "title": "Image 3", "folder": "Folder 1" },
{ "thumb": "../userfiles/img/min/m_4.jpg", "image": "../userfiles/img/4.jpg", "title": "Image 4", "folder": "Folder 1" },
{ "thumb": "../userfiles/img/min/m_5.jpg", "image": "../userfiles/img/5.jpg", "title": "Image 5", "folder": "Folder 1" }
]
```

This is my php file that adds an element to the file data.jon

**add_json.php**

```
<?
$dir_thumb  = '../userfiles/img/thumb/6_m.jpg';
$dir_img    = '../userfiles/img/6.jpg'; 
$title      = 'img_6';     
$tipo_image = 'news';

$json        = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data        = json_decode($json);

$data[]     = array(
             'thumb'=>  $dir_thumb,
             'image'=>  $dir_img,
             'title'=>  $title,
             'folder'=> $tipo_image         
        );
file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data));
?>
```

This is the resulting file data.json

**data.json** (after executing the file add_json.php)

```
[   
{"thumb":"..\/userfiles\/img\/min\/m_1.jpg","image":"..\/userfiles\/img\/1.jpg","title":"Image 1","folder":"Folder 1"},
{"thumb":"..\/userfiles\/img\/min\/m_2.jpg","image":"..\/userfiles\/img\/2.jpg","title":"Image 2","folder":"Folder 1"},
{"thumb":"..\/userfiles\/img\/min\/m_3.jpg","image":"..\/userfiles\/img\/3.jpg","title":"Image 3","folder":"Folder 1"},
{"thumb":"..\/userfiles\/img\/min\/m_4.jpg","image":"..\/userfiles\/img\/4.jpg","title":"Image 4","folder":"Folder 1"},
{"thumb":"..\/userfiles\/img\/min\/m_5.jpg","image":"..\/userfiles\/img\/5.jpg","title":"Image 5","folder":"Folder 1"},
{"thumb":"..\/userfiles\/img\/thumb\/6_m.jpg","image":"..\/userfiles\/img\/6.jpg","title":"img_6","folder":"news"}  
]
```

What I do to remove backslashes? Thanks for your help

Comment: That's just PHP overkill. Don't worry, the JSON is still valid, and the strings have **exactly** the same value they would have without the unnecessary backslashes.

Comment: Or `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as mentioned in one of the other dozens of duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent that with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option to `json_encode`, see [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Note, though, that it's just PHP overkill. The JSON is still valid, and the strings have **exactly** the same sequence of characters in them that they would have without the unnecessary escape characters.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? Please explain.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have two days with this problem "no problem"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove those backslashes, they're just escaping characters.

After reading that JSON formatted string, those sequences of `\/` will be automatically converted to `/`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have two days with this problem "no problem"

Answer (score 1):

What you have is perfectly valid JSON, but if you want to remove it, you can do it with the [`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) constant:

```
file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have two days with this problem "no problem"

Comment: @FranciscoJoséSeguraNoya: Your issue is now solved?